# Swift_TransportException : LaravelApp Failed To Send Email From Shared Hosting Server (Hostinger)

Tags: laravel, email

I want to sent email from larevel app from shared hosting server.

Here is the configuration in .env file :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.in
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

I have also tried this :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.in
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

also tried with **sendmail** driver

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.in
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

But Any of these not working , failed to send email .
Please Help Me To Solve out this problem.

I Got this error :

[image]

Below is my `config/mail.php`

```
<?php

 return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'sendmail'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mx1.hostinger.in'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'notification@mydomain.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', ''),
],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',



'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
];
```

Comment: Set it up in an email client, see if works there. If it doesn't, get some help from your hosting provider.

Comment: email is sent when i use php mail() function

Comment: i have also tested with nodemailer (Node Js),  email successfully sent , but when using laravel...it gives me error

Comment: also tested with : https://www.smtper.net/ .....it works

Comment: i have also tested with PHPMailer , it works fine

Comment: can you try first option which you mentioned in your question, except change MAIL_ENCRYPTION to tls instead of null ?

Comment: not wroking , give same erro

Answer (score 1):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@inclick24.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="your_pass"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@inclick24.com
```

This one worked like charm in updated settings...

Answer (score 0):

Use ssl on the mail encryption

1. MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
2. MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.in
3. MAIL_PORT=587
4. MAIL_USERNAME=****
5. MAIL_PASSWORD=****
6. MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl

And make sure the host and port details in your config/mail.php file are same as the .env file.

Comment: Could you kindly paste the contents your config/mail.php

Comment: Ok. Make sure that:
1.You have enabled SMTP Service on your hostinger account
2.You are sending the email to an existing email account.

Comment: read above comments ...email is sent by all other methods but not sent using laravel Mail

Comment: I have already tried all possible different combination , but any of not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add 'MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS' and 'MAIL_FROM_NAME'.

This works for me:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mx1.hostinger.com.br
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=yourmail@domain.com.br
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=yourmail@domain.com.br
MAIL_FROM_NAME=yourname
```